# Get min date from another table with filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I got two tables. There is a relationship between id and user id column. I want to add a calculated column in the user table with the first transaction of the user, for invoice type 'A'.

When I use:
`Calculate(min(Transaction[transaction date]))` it works fine, but I need to filter on invoice type. When I use `Calculate(min(Transaction[transaction date]),Filter(Transaction,Invoice type="A"))` I only get 2021-02-01 and the realtionship does not work.

What is the most efficent way to achieve this?

User table:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith |
| 2 | Alan Walker |

Transaction table:

| user id | transaction date | Invoice type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 | A |
| 1 | 2021-02-25 | A |
| 1 | 2021-02-25 | B |
| 2 | 2021-03-05 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-23 | B |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct DAX code for your calculated column, just drop the `FILTER` statement, since that changes your filter context within the `CALCULATE` to look at all rows where `Invoice type = "A"`, regardless of `User ID`.

```
Minimum Date = 
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'Transaction'[transaction date] ),
    'Transaction'[Invoice type] = "A"
)
```

Since you need context transition to provide you the row context from the `Users` table to the `Transactions` table, you can alternatively use this sort of filtering statement, where the table you are filtering on is also provided within the current filter context of your row in `Users`:

```
Min Date = 
CALCULATE ( 
    MIN ( 'Transaction'[transaction date] ) , 
    FILTER ( 
        CALCULATETABLE ( 'Transaction' ) , 
        'Transaction'[Invoice type] = "A"
    )
)
```